# Google Sheets script not recognizing Split function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, split

Here is my code. For some reason Sheets is saying that the "Split function is not recognized".

```
function distance3(latlon1, latlon2){
  var [lat1, lon1] = split(latlon1,",");
  var [lat2, lon2] = split(latlon2,",");
  var R = 6371000; // radius of the earth in meters, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius
  var dLat = (lat2-lat1) * Math.PI / 180; // Convert degrees to radians
  var dLon = (lon2-lon1) * Math.PI / 180; // Convert degrees to radians
  var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
          Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180 ) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180 ) *
          Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
  var d = R * c;

  // Distance in meters, rounded to an integer.
  return Math.round(d)*0.000621371;
}
```

THANK YOU!

Comment: Check the Javascript documentation on the split function. [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var [lat1, lon1] = latlon1.split(",");
```

Comment: Giving me TypeError: Cannot call method "split" of undefined. (line 2, file "distance")

Comment: This means one of your vars, latlon1 or latlon2 is undefined. if you call .split on a string it works. try "1,2".split(",") for instance. You should check to see why your function arguments are undefined then

Comment: Please show how you are calling the function. My guess is that latlon1, and latlon2 are not arrays.  They're probably object with key/value pairs